# d3 check which dataset within function

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js

I currently have 2 charts, one on top the other.  The which set of data is associated with the top and bottom is determined dynamically.  I want to also determine the color of the top and bottom chart based on which dataset is being used.  I.E. one dataset is associated with Males, one with Females, females should be red, males blue.  The way I'm doing it right now is like this:

```
 bar2.append("rect")
    .attr("height", function(d) { return heightBottom - bottomScale(d) })
    .attr("width", barWidth - 1)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return dataMale.indexOf(d) !== -1 ? "blue" : "red";
    });
```

But in the case where both datasets have the same value, things could get messed up.  Is there a better way to do this?  Here's the code:

```
var dataMale = [577661, 1552631, 447955, 55570, 10391, 3146, 24462];
var dataFemale = [221395, 1156634, 151738, 20167, 5157, 1598, 7545];

var dataTop, dataBottom;
var maleMax = d3.max(dataMale), femaleMax = d3.max(dataFemale);
var maleFemaleTotal = maleMax + femaleMax;
var maleMaxOfAll = maleMax > femaleMax;



var ratioMale = maleMax/maleFemaleTotal;
var ratioFemale = femaleMax/maleFemaleTotal;

if (d3.max(dataMale) > d3.max(dataFemale)) {
    dataTop = dataMale;
    dataBottom = dataFemale;
} else {
    dataTop = dataFemale;
    dataBottom = dataMale;
}

var width = 960,
fullHeight = 550,
wrapperHeight = fullHeight + 200,
heightTop, 
heightBottom;

if (maleMaxOfAll) {
    heightTop = fullHeight * ratioMale;
    heightBottom = fullHeight * ratioFemale;
} else {
    heightTop = fullHeight * ratioFemale;
    heightBottom = fullHeight * ratioMale;
}

var topScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(dataTop)])
    .range([heightTop, 0]);

var bottomScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(dataBottom)])
    .range([heightBottom, 0]);

var axisScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(dataTop)
    .rangeBands([0, width]);

var axisScale2 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(dataBottom)
    .rangeBands([0, width]);
    // .range([0, 960]);

var chart = d3.select(".chart")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", wrapperHeight);

var chart1 = chart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "chart-one")
    .attr("height", heightTop)
    .attr("width", width);


var chart2 = chart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "chart-two")
    .attr("transform", function() { return "translate(0," + (heightTop + 90) + ")"; })
    .attr("height", heightBottom)
    .attr("width", width);

var barWidth = width / dataMale.length;

var bar = d3.select(".chart-one")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(dataTop)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "one")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + i * barWidth + ", 0)"; });

bar.append("rect")
    .attr("y", function(d) { return topScale(d) + 50; })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return heightTop - topScale(d); })
    .attr("width", barWidth - 1)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return dataMale.indexOf(d) !== -1 ? "blue" : "red";
    });

var bar2 = d3.select(".chart-two")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(dataBottom)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "two")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + i * barWidth + ",0)"; });

bar2.append("rect")
    .attr("height", function(d) { return heightBottom - bottomScale(d) })
    .attr("width", barWidth - 1)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return dataMale.indexOf(d) !== -1 ? "blue" : "red";
    });

var sharedAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(axisScale)
    .tickValues(dataTop);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(axisScale)
    .tickValues(dataTop);
    // .tickPadding([-10]);
    // .orient("top");
var xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(axisScale)
    .tickValues(dataTop)
    .tickPadding([15]);

var xAxis3 = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(axisScale)
    .tickValues(dataTop)
    .tickPadding(27);

var xBotAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(axisScale2)
    .orient("top")
    .tickValues(dataBottom);

d3.select(".chart-one").append("g").attr("class", "axis").call(xAxis);
d3.select(".chart-one").append("g").attr("class", "axis").call(xAxis2);
d3.select(".chart-one").append("g").attr("class", "axis").call(xAxis3);
d3.select(".chart").append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0," + (heightTop + 62) + ")").attr("class", "axis").call(sharedAxis);

d3.select(".chart-two").append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0, " + (heightBottom + 25) + ")").attr("class", "axis").call(xBotAxis);
d3.select(".chart-two").append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0, " + (heightBottom + 37) + ")").attr("class", "axis").call(xBotAxis);
d3.select(".chart-two").append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0, " + (heightBottom + 49) + ")").attr("class", "axis").call(xBotAxis);
```

Comment: I would make what kind of data set it is part of the data, e.g. have an attribute "type".

Comment: would that mess up the data bind though? cuz im binding an array to the groups?

Comment: Not sure what you mean when you say that you bind an array to the groups, but I can't see how it would mess things up.

Comment: For instance here var bar = d3.select(".chart-one")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(dataTop) 
I'm binding the array so that it makes that many "rects".  So when I append the rects the "d" in the functions refers to that piece of data.  I jsut don't see how if I were to make the data look like this {"values": array, "gender": "male"}; I could bind the array and access d.gender within bar.append("rect").style("fill", function(d) {
      return dataMale.indexOf(d) !== -1 ? "blue" : "red";
     });

Comment: You wouldn't need to -- you would do `.data(dataTop)` and then `.style("fill", dataTop.gender == "male" ? "blue" : "red")`.

Comment: Wow. Talk about missing something right under your eyes.  Thanks again Lars.

Comment: No problem. I'll post that as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make the type part of the data. Assuming that you add it as a new attribute `gender`, you could then do something like

```
var dataTop = male;
// more code
var bar = d3.select(".chart-one")
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(dataTop)
  .enter().append("g");
bar.append("rect")
   .style("fill", dataTop.gender == "male" ? "blue" : "red");
```

Comment: maybe you should add this  {"values": array, "gender": "male"};  Don't know if this question/answer is clear enough to help anyone.

Comment: You can have attributes on an array, so technically the separate `values` member isn't necessary.